# Sentence classification: Why does my embedding not reduce the shape of the subsequent layer?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, shapes, keras-layer, embedding

I want to embed sentences that all contain 5 words and a my training-set has a total vocabulary of 10000 words. I use this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
vocab_size = 10000

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,vocab_size), name="input", )
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 64)(inputs)
conv2d_1 = Conv2D(        filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),
                  strides =(1), padding = 'SAME',)(embedding)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv2d_1)
model.summary()
```

After running I get:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           [(None, 5, 10000)]        0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_105 (Embedding)    (None, 5, 10000, 64)      640000    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_102 (Conv2D)          (None, 5, 10000, 32)      18464     
=================================================================
```

I want to do the embedding to convert the sparse 10000x5 tensor to a dense 64x5 tensor. Apparently that doesn't work as intended, so my question is: Why is the shape of the next layer not `(None, 5, 64, 32)` instead of  `(None, 5, 10000, 32)`? How can I achieve the compactization?